# no encuentro el error. Es un buscador pero no me hace la consulta y sale error en la linea de... echo $row

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

```
<?php
include("conexionBasesDatos.php");

$Conexion=conectarse();
echo "esesectado";

IF(isset($_GET['enviarr'])) {
    $busqueda = $_GET['busqueda'];
    $consulta = $Conexion->query("SELECT * FROM producto WHERE Nombre LIKE '%$busqueda%'");

    while ($row = $consulta->fetch_array()); {
        echo $row['Nombre'];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Existe el campo Nombre en tu tabla producto?

Answer (score 1):

El problema creo que es el ; que hay en el while, quítalo y prueba de nuevo.

```
while ($row = $consulta->fetch_array()) {
    echo $row['Nombre'];
}
```

Un saludo

Answer (score -1):

yo usaria foreach así:

```
<?php

 foreach($consulta as $row){
     echo $row['nombre'];
 }
```

o utiliza
`print_r($consulta)` o `print_r($row)` para obtener la info de o que estás obteniendo, ayuda si adjuntas el error que te sale